# Selecting odd numbers of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

HI I have this Matlab code which is picking the odd number of rows and columns from Residuals Matrix. I would like to convert this piece of code from to Python. Could you please let me know if my code is correct.

Matlab code:

```
NewRes(:,:,Channel,:) = Residuals([1:2:size(Residuals,1)],[1:2:size(Residuals,1)],Channel,:);
```

Python code:

```
NewRes[:, :, Channel, :] = Residuals(Residuals[::2], Residuals[::2], Channel, :)
```

Does my code represent the even number of rows and columns? How can be size(Residuals,1) can be considered.

example output from matlab code

```
Residuals =

     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     8     9     3     1

>>  Residuals([1:2:size(Residuals,1)],[1:2:size(Residuals,1)], :, :);
>> Residuals

Residuals =

     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     8     9     3     1

>> Newres = Residuals([1:2:size(Residuals,1)],[1:2:size(Residuals,1)], :, :);
>> Newres

Newres =

     1     3
     8     3
```

Comment: It would be a lot better if you'd just provide a [mcve] with some input and indicate what you want to get out of it. You can also run your matlab code, and then your python code and see if the output is the same (obviously).

Comment: I just added a demo here.

Comment: Might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792658/1011724. It's impossible to say without sample data but you might want this: `NewRes[: Channel, :, :] = Residuals[:, Channel, ::2, ::2]`. The change in order due python being row major and matlab bein column major.

Comment: Why does your MATLAB code index the matrix with 4 dimensions when it only has two? i.e. why isn't it simply `Newres = Residuals(1:2:end, 1:2:end)`. Because the python equivalent python (numpy I assume) for that is just `Newres = Residuals[::2, ::2]`

Comment: I just gave an example how it is extracting rows and columns. It is considereing dimensions as it represent tensor in matlab.

Comment: @PRB but your output in MATLAB shows that it only has two dimensions...?

Comment: But either way the correct syntax for your `Residuals(Residuals[::2], Residuals[::2], Channel, :)` is `Residuals[::2, ::2, Channel, :]` with the caveat that the order of the dimensions might change as noted in the link I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iloc` is certainly the way to go:

```
df.iloc[::2, ::2]
```

Comment: I think this is select the even number of row , right  ?

Comment: Ah, that's true. I was thinking in terms of indices. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `.iloc` with `%`

```
df.iloc[np.arange(df.shape[0]) % 2 == 0, np.arange(df.shape[1]) % 2 == 0]
   1  3
0  1  3
2  8  3
```